# Color storm text effect in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

Can someone direct me to a JavaScript text animation for a color storm effect? I don't have a perfect example/video that I can share to add more clarity. However, the following URL is something close I found in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xuep/6/).

The actual requirement is to have a more storm-like effect, i.e. vertically randomize the colors as they flow in. And asymmetrically distribute the colors along the height of a character. Something that makes it feel as if a storm of colors is passing through.

Any pointers are appreciated.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// add animation-delay properties to span elements

var animTime = 6, // time for the animation in seconds
    hueChange = 3, // the hue change from one span element to the next
    prefixes = ["", "-webkit-", "-moz-", "-o-"],
    numPrefixes = prefixes.length;

$('.unicorn').find('span').each(function (i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numPrefixes; j++) {
        $(this).css(prefixes[j] + 'animation-delay', (animTime * ((i * hueChange) % 360) / 360) - animTime + 's');
    }
});

// needed to avoid Chrome bug:
$('.unicorn').one('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).addClass('animate');
});
```

```css
.unicorn.animate span {
    -webkit-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
    -moz-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
    -o-animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
    animation: colorRotate 6s linear 0s infinite;
    
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.unicorn:hover span {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -o-animation-play-state: running;
    animation-play-state: running;
}
@-webkit-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
@keyframes colorRotate {
    from {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
    16.6% {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    }
    33.3% {
        color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
    }
    50% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 255);
    }
    66.6% {
        color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    }
    83.3% {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
    }
    to {
        color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<p class="unicorn"> <span style="color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%);">L</span><span style="color: hsl(4, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(7, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(10, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(13, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(16, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(19, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(23, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(26, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(29, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(32, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(35, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(38, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(42, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(45, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(48, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(51, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(54, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(57, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(60, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(64, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(67, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(70, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(73, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(76, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(79, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(83, 100%, 50%);">,</span><span style="color: hsl(86, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(89, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(92, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(95, 100%, 50%);">n</span><span style="color: hsl(98, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(102, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(105, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(108, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(111, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(114, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(117, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(120, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(124, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(127, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(130, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(133, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(136, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(139, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(143, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(146, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(149, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(152, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(155, 100%, 50%);">n</span><span style="color: hsl(158, 100%, 50%);">g</span><span style="color: hsl(162, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(165, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(168, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(171, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(174, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(177, 100%, 50%);">.</span><span style="color: hsl(180, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(184, 100%, 50%);">C</span><span style="color: hsl(187, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(190, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(193, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(196, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(199, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(203, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(206, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(209, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(212, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(215, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(218, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(222, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(225, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(228, 100%, 50%);">q</span><span style="color: hsl(231, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(234, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(237, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(240, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(244, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(247, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(250, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(253, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(256, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(259, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(263, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(266, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(269, 100%, 50%);">d</span><span style="color: hsl(272, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(275, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(278, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(282, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(285, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(288, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(291, 100%, 50%);">q</span><span style="color: hsl(294, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(297, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(300, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(304, 100%, 50%);">m</span><span style="color: hsl(307, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(310, 100%, 50%);">l</span><span style="color: hsl(313, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(316, 100%, 50%);">s</span><span style="color: hsl(319, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(323, 100%, 50%);">i</span><span style="color: hsl(326, 100%, 50%);">a</span><span style="color: hsl(329, 100%, 50%);">e</span><span style="color: hsl(332, 100%, 50%);"> </span><span style="color: hsl(335, 100%, 50%);">c</span><span style="color: hsl(338, 100%, 50%);">o</span><span style="color: hsl(342, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(345, 100%, 50%);">r</span><span style="color: hsl(348, 100%, 50%);">u</span><span style="color: hsl(351, 100%, 50%);">p</span><span style="color: hsl(354, 100%, 50%);">t</span><span style="color: hsl(357, 100%, 50%);">i</span>
```

Comment: the differences are vertical and asymmetrically? some kind of this http://codepen.io/arcs/pen/bpgzwZ?

Comment: Umm, no. I was asking for additional randomization in the way colors are flowing in the jsfiddle example. The example I shared is pretty close.

Comment: i guess u mean control the speed of flow, if u want a prepared randomization  and loop this clip, just modify the percentage in keyframes colorRotate, make some color stay longer, if u want sometime flow faster and sometime flow slower, u need use another way, background-clip, i'll make a fiddle for it later

Comment: I will wait for your fiddle. However, the main question was to have multiple colors flow in simultaneously, and horizontally. Imagine different colored paint buckets poured simultaneously from the left. The top part of letter "L" could be red while the bottom part is "blue", and similarly flow towards the right with varying heights of each color.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://codepen.io/postor/pen/OXoagV) it is smooth now

```js
var $c = $('.clip');
var posX = 0;
var posY = 0;
var timeout = Math.random()*1000;

function flow(){
  console.log([$c,posX,posY]);
  posX+=500;
  posY+=500;
  timeout = Math.random()*1000;
  $c.css('-webkit-transition', (timeout/1000)+'s linear');
  $c.css('background-position',posX+'px '+posY+'px');
  setTimeout(flow,timeout)
}
flow();
```

```css
.clip {
  font-size: 260px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 0px, #00ff00 235.7px, #0000ff 471.4px, #ff0000 707.1px);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.clip.d45 {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0000 0px, #00ff00 235.7px, #0000ff 471.4px, #ff0000 707.1px);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clip">background clip clip </div>
```